# result.data?.extras?.get("data") is deprecated

Tags: image, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, android-glide

I try to get a picture from phone's camera and everuthing works but the following method is deprecated:

```
result.data?.extras?.get("data")
```

How can I update that? The full method is:

```
private val pickImage1 = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result  ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val uriImage = result.data?.extras?.get("data")
                Glide.with(requireContext()).load(uriImage).override(250, 250)
                    .into(binding!!.stepDescriptionImageView)
                if (uriImage != null)
                    imageURI = uriImage.toString()
            }
        }
```

And I call it:

```
pickImage1.launch(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  val selectedPhotoUri = data.data
            try {
                selectedPhotoUri?.let {
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                            this.contentResolver,
                            selectedPhotoUri
                        )
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    } else {
                        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
                        val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).